# How to count newly enrolled students by month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data table of students with individual enrollment dates. I am struggling to write a DAX measure that shows how many students enrolled in each month of the program year.

My unsuccessful attempts:

```
ReplacedDrop.TEST = CALCULATE(COUNT('COMP PY 25'[ENROLLMENT DATE]),FILTER('EnrollmentDateTable.TEST',ENDOFMONTH('EnrollmentDateTable.TEST'[Date])))

ReplacedDrop.TEST = CALCULATE(COUNT('COMP PY 25'[ENROLLMENT DATE]),FILTER('COMP PY 25','COMP PY 25'[ENROLLMENT DATE] <= DATE(2020,09,01)))-CALCULATE(COUNT('COMP PY 25'[DROP DATE]),FILTER('COMP PY 25','COMP PY 25'[DROP DATE] <= DATE(2020,09,01))) 

ReplacedDrop.TEST = CALCULATE(COUNT('COMP PY 25'[ENROLLMENT DATE]),FILTER('COMP PY 25','COMP PY 25'[ENROLLMENT DATE] = ENDOFMONTH('COMP PY 25'[ENROLLMENT DATE])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the DAX measure to work!

Here is a screenshot of measure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaO97.png)